# Generate md5 hash in Angular 5

Tags: angular, md5

In angular, I want to generate a MD5 hash, so I tried installing `npm` modules. I tried 'crypto-js', 'angular-md5', but a lot of them with no results.

Finally, I tried with 'ts-md5' and is throwing me an error, as all the others.

First `npm install --save ts-md5`

and then:

```
import {Md5} from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    constructor(
        private MD5: Md5
    ) { }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
[Error] ERROR – Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HeroService -> Md5]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HeroService -> Md5]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Md5!
get
resolveToken
tryResolveToken
[...]
```

Is there a better module to encrypt in md5? How can I solve this error?

Comment: Have you added `Md5` to the providers array in your *app.module.ts*? It would seem that is all you are missing.

Comment: **MD5 is not encryption**, not is a cryptographic hash function should rarely be used un new work because it is not very secure, SHS256 is a reasonable replacement for MD5.

Comment: I know MD5 is not encryption and it's recommended to use a better system for encryption. But I need md5 to authenticate in the marvel developers api, and in this case, it must be md5 and not another one.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Finally the best way to do it is importing it directly in the component where I have to use it and call it with `new Md5()`.

```
import {Md5} from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';

const md5 = new Md5();
console.log(md5.appendStr('hello').end());
```

Thanks to all for the quick responses.

Comment: If you're using it like regular `new Md5()` constructor (and you likely should, because it cannot benefit from DI and shouldn't be a singleton), you don't need to have Md5 in the module.

Comment: I have tried just now, and you are absolutely right. So I'm going to edit my response.

Comment: I tried a number of Crypto / Digest libraries and this was the first that worked without any extra work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You cannot inject MD5 class like this, because angular dependency injection framework does not know how to provide it. You can only ask for classes that have been provided in `@NgModule` providers or that have been added to providers by other imported `@NgModules`.

You should remove `private MD5: Md` from the constructor and see if it works. Also check out [angular cli global scripts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts).